# android play youtube video on a new window

Tags: java, android

If I load www.youtube.com url on a webview and select any video, doesn't trigger new window with player. Should I set something for it on manifest? If I use standard browser works! Event shouldOverrideUrlLoading or any other are not fired. Thank you

```
webviewA.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webviewA.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webviewA.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webviewA.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webviewA.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webviewA.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
        webviewA.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webviewA.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webviewA.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);

        webviewA.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
        webviewA.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);

        webviewA.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        webviewA.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        webviewA.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

if (savedInstanceState == null){
            String Url = "www.youtube.com/my-desired_channel";
            webviewA.loadUrl(Url);
        }
```

event not fired,

```
 @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
    not fired!!
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like -

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abcde")));
```

EDIT: Try this

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
{
 public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
 {
  // YouTube video link
  if (url.startsWith("vnd.youtube:"))
  {
   int n = url.indexOf("?");
   if (n > 0)
   {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(String.format("http://www.youtube.com/v/%s", url.substring("vnd.youtube:".length(),n)));
   }
   return (true);
  }

  return (false);
 }
});
```

Comment: ok, but where?? shouldOverrideUrlLoading is not fired when click on youtube video

Comment: you are using shouldOverrideUrlLoading and it is not fired when click on youtube video

Comment: webview is displaying youtube channel and when click on video, no event  is fired. There is no url because event is not triggered!

Comment: which version of android are you using? this is on a device right?

Comment: posted, hope could help. Android 2.3.7 and tested on Sony Xperia U and SonyExperia Neo

Comment: what about the part where you specify the shouldOverrideUrlLoading method

Comment: posted but this is main problem, this event

Comment: I finally found how to trigger shouldOverrideUrl event but was not an easy task... After that, your code works great! really thankful!

Comment: @Jaume could you post what worked for you? Will be helpful to others in future :)

Comment: sure, I set "fake" user agent for webview modifying webviewB.getSettings().setUserAgentString property.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to state the obvious but have you included the "INTERNET" permission in your manifest file?

EDIT: added code just to be sure

it should be something like this in your manifest

```
<manifest ... >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
...
</manifest>
```

Comment: That doesn't make much sense, he is already able to use the WebView.